# Bash scripting parameter

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

Been trying to make this code exit when a paramater is not entered for "circum" or the number is negative

```
#!/bin/bash

pi=3.1415
echo "Enter a circumference"
read circum
rad=$( echo "scale=2;$circum / (2 * $pi)" | bc )
printf "Radius: %.4f\n" $rad
area=$( echo "scale=2;$pi * $rad * $rad" | bc )
printf "Area: %.4f\n" $area
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need an if statement that processes the circum variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

pi=3.1415
echo "Enter a circumference"
read circum
if grep -Ev '^[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?$' <<< $circum || [[ "$circum" -lt 0 ]]
then
        echo "Please enter a positive number"
        exit
fi
rad=$( echo "scale=2;$circum / (2 * $pi)" | bc )
printf "Radius: %.4f\n" $rad
area=$( echo "scale=2;$pi * $rad * $rad" | bc )
printf "Area: %.4f\n" $area
```

Do an inverse check for one or more digits then 0 or 1 instances of a single full stop and 1 or more digits. Also do a check for circum being less than 0. In any of these case, print an error message and exit otherwise continue.